# UIButton - turning off or reduing "selection/hold down" tint colour

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, tint

I would like a way to either reduce the darkness change (or turn off as a last resort) that you get when you hold down a UIButton on iOS 7 and 6. It looks horrible due to the image on the button when selected

Thanks

Dylan

Answer (score 0):

You can set different images and/or background images based on the `UIControlState`.
For example in case of images:

```
[comment_notification setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Normal state

[comment_notification setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2"] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//pressed and released state

[comment_notification setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3"] forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];//pressed state
```

or in case of background colour, add targets:

```
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(performLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(releasedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

and in the target method, like buttonpressed:

```
- (void) buttonpressed:(UIButton*)button{

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

and so on for respective states

Comment: I'll check, and get back to you with the full answer.